# Trouble with specific class inheritance behaviour

Tags: python, inheritance

So I am trying to get my data structure set up for an automated generator I am writing for a roleplaying game and I am having trouble with some specific inheritance quirks. Here is an excerpt of the data structure.

```
class data():
   def __init__(self):
      self.races = Races()
class Races(data):
   def __init__(self):
      self.humans = Humans()
class Humans(Races):
   def __init__(self):
      self.Characteristics = {
            'Brawn':2,
            'Agility':2,
            'Intellect':2,
            'Cunning':2,
            'Willpower':2,
            'Presence':2
            }
```

There is a lot more in the structure but this is just a bottom to top overview. I also know it is indented weirdly but that is strictly stack overflow.

Now I wish to have two behaviors from this object.
The ability to call any characteristic with 
`data.races.humans.Characteristic['brawn']`
as the calling format.

And too also be able to iterate through subclasses with a generator like:
`(subclass for subclass in data.races.__subclasses__())`

obviously after I have instantiated the object.

Now I have tried changing the structure several times and I can get it so EITHER I can call it with dot notation, but it returns `AttributeError: 'Races' object has no attribute '__subclasses__'`

Or vice versa by completely separating it into a more traditional structure but then I cannot call in dot notation and this makes it very hard to keep everything organized and readable.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong or a more Pythonic way to approach the problem?

Comment: Be careful - it sounds like you want composition, not inheritance. Humans may be a Race, but Races aren't a data.

Comment: When they are made in the exact same way how are Humans linked to Races but Races not to data? 

The reason they are all relating to the same top level object is that there are different pieces of data and I wish to put it all in its own module and instantiate one object.

Comment: @KirkReynolds `data`, instead of being single class that `Race` inherits from, can simply be a list of classes: `races = [Human, Elf, Dwarf, ... ]`, to use my answer as a starting point. It really all depends on how you need to model your data. I tried giving just a quick taste in my answer, but your question is too broad to answer usefully here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start in the middle. Presumably, a character of any race has the same attributes, just different values for those attributes.

```
class Race:
    def __init__(self):
        self.life = 100  # 100% healthy

class Humanoid(Race):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.legs = 2

class Insectoid(Race):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.legs = 8

class Human(Humanoid):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.brawn = 2
        self.agility = 2
        self.intellect = 2
        self.cunning = 2,
        self.willpower = 2
        self.presence = 2

class Elf(Humanoid):
    def __init__(self):
        super.__init__()
        self.brawn = 1
        self.agility = 3
        self.intellect = 3
        self.cunning = 2
        self.willpower = 3
        self.presence = 1
```

Now, any particular character would be instantiated as the correct class:

```
some_elf_1 = Elf()
some_human_1 = Human()
some_human_2 = Human()

for character in [some_elf_1, some_human_1, some_human_2]:
    print("Brawn: ", character.brawn)
```

In the preceding, it doesn't matter what the actual type of each character is; as long as you know that it is some subclass of `Race` (or an instance of `Race` itself), it will have a `brawn` attribute that you can access.

You `data` class doesn't really seem necessary without more detail.

Comment: I was doing that to allow me to call it all at once from a different module, however looking at your solution it does seem like it would work for me. However there could be potentially hundreds of varying races (This is Star Wars after all!) and I would like to avoid initializing them all if possible. That is why I was hoping I could put them all under one object - call a specific one if necessary but easily iterate over them without writing a whole bunch of boilerplate code to initialize the objects.

Comment: Are any of the races related? You can have a more complicated hierarchy than what I show. `Race.__init__` can do initialization that is common to any race, and you can create intermediate classes: think of how life on earth is organized by kingdom, phylum, order, class, family, genus, species. Each phylum would be a class that extends kingdom, each order extends a phylum, etc. Further, the `__init__` method for each parent is called from the `__init__` method of the children. (I'll add an example to the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

So, While the answer given put me on the right track I realized what I needed and am just throwing in my lot for any poor souls.

Firstly - I realized what was wrong with my generator, I was calling on the initialized object instead of the class object. Objects do not have a **subclasses** attrib and I was mis-informed by most of the guides I read!

Secondly, I considered using a metaclass to get the iterating behavior I wanted from my objects can simply be achieved with a registry attribute that is a dict of all the initialized subclasses.

```
lass Races(data):
def __init__(self):
    self.humans = Humans()
    self.droids = Droids()
    self.twileks = Twileks()
    self.registry = {
            'humans':self.humans,
            'droids':self.droids,
            'twileks':self.twileks
            }
```

This allows me to iterate through certain values for different races after they have been initialized.

Thanks for all the great answers!